# SQL Query to lookup on same table from which selecting the records

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

Sample records :

```
Custid pref_location
C1     PUNE
C1     MUMBAI
c1     DELHI    
C2     PUNE
C2     MUMBAI
C3     MUMBAI  
c4     PUNE
C5     DELHI
```

I want to fetch records where pref location is only PUNE or MUMBAI .I am doing it with help of below query :

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP_PRE_LOCATION E1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM EMP_PRE_LOCATION E2 
        WHERE E2.EID=E1.EID AND E2.PRE_LOCATION in ('PUNE','MUMBAI'))
AND NOT  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
        FROM EMP_PRE_LOCATION E3 
        WHERE E3.EID=E1.EID AND E3.PRE_LOCATION NOT in('PUNE','MUMBAI'));
```

Is their any better way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want:

```
SELECT E1.*
FROM EMP_PRE_LOCATION E1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM EMP_PRE_LOCATION E2 
                  WHERE E2.EID = E1.EID AND
                        E2.PRE_LOCATION NOT IN ('PUNE', 'MUMBAI')
                 );
```

If you just want employees in only those two locations, then you can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT E1.EID
FROM EMP_PRE_LOCATION E1
GROUP BY E1.EID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN E1.PRE_LOCATION NOT IN ('PUNE', 'MUMBAI') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

You can add `LISTAGG(E1.PRE_LOCATION, ',')` if you want a list of the locations.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP_PRE_LOCATION
WHERE pref_location ='PUNE' OR pref_location ='MUMBAI'
```

Answer (score 0):

Second `WHERE` clause would do the you want :

```
SELECT E1.*
FROM EMP_PRE_LOCATION E1
WHERE E1.PRE_LOCATION IN ('PUNE','MUMBAI') AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM EMP_PRE_LOCATION E3 
                  WHERE E3.EID = E1.EID AND E3.PRE_LOCATION NOT IN ('PUNE','MUMBAI')
                 );
```

This would return only `EID`s which have only `LOCATION IN ('PUNE','MUMBAI')`.

Comment: Hi Yogesh, Thanks for your reply !
 Query from Gordon is doing exactly same thing . We do not need E1.PRE_LOCATION IN ('PUNE','MUMBAI') clause .